# Доработка анимации движения шарика по холсту, а именно изменение цвета при отталкивании от стенки в Tkinter, Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

Реализовал анимацию движения шарика в том направлении, куда кликает пользователь. И вот хотелось бы добавить такое действие как изменение цвета шарика при отталкивании от стенки. Можете подсказать как это реализовать? Буду признателен за помощь!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
import math


class GameBall:
   def __init__(self, width=400, height=400):
       self.vx = 1
       self.vy = 1
       self.t = 0
       self.dt = 1
       self.i = 0
       self.height = height
       self.width = width
       self.c = Canvas(root, width=self.width, height=self.height, bg="white")
       self.c.pack()
       self.rad = 20
       self.ball = self.c.create_oval(self.width // 2 - self.rad, self.height // 2 - self.rad,
                                   self.width // 2 + self.rad, self.height // 2 + self.rad, fill='green')

       self.c.bind('<Button-1>', self.onclick)
       root.after(10, self.onframe)

   def onclick(self, event):
       self.p = self.c.coords(self.ball)
       self.dx = event.x - self.p[0]
       self.dy = event.y - self.p[1]

       self.r = math.sqrt(self.dx ** 2 + self.dy ** 2)

       self.vx = self.dx / self.r
       self.vy = self.dy / self.r

       self.t += self.dt
       self.p[0] += self.vx + 10
       self.p[1] += self.vy + 10

       if 200 > self.dx >= 100 or 200 > self.dy >= 100 or -200 < self.dx <= -100 or -200 < self.dy <= -100:
           self.dt = 2
       elif 300 > self.dx >= 200 or 300 > self.dy >= 200 or -300 < self.dx <= -200 or -300 < self.dy <= -200:
           self.dt = 4
       elif 500 > self.dx >= 300 or 500 > self.dy >= 300 or -500 < self.dx <= -300 or -500 < self.dy <= -300:
           self.dt = 7
       elif self.dx >= 500 or self.dy >= 500 or self.dx <= -500 or self.dy <= -500:
           self.dt = 10
       else:
           self.dt = 1
       print(self.dx, self.dy, self.dt)

   def onframe(self):
       self.c.move(self.ball, self.dt * self.vx, self.dt * self.vy)
       self.p = self.c.coords(self.ball)

       if self.p[1] < 0 or self.p[1] > self.height - 2 * self.rad:
           self.vy = -self.vy

       if self.p[0] < 0 or self.p[0] > self.width - 2 * self.rad:
           self.vx = -self.vx

       root.after(10, self.onframe)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(False, False)
    GameBall()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создайте список цветов. Названия можно взять отсюда: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color_list.html, например

```
COLORS = ('blue', 'brown', 'burlywood', 'cadetblue')
```

2. Создайте метод класса GameBall изменения цвета шарика, ставя следующий цвет из списка, при помощи метода self.c.itemconfig(self.ball, fill=
3. Вызывайте этот метод, при столкновении шарика со стенкой.